# Aligning parent div in div centered and the child divs aligned left

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to get a parent div (`#account_thumbs`) inside a div (`#useruploads`) (yes, it's technically a child div) to get centered in that div, while the child divs (`.imagethumb`) of said parent div are going to be aligned-left.

But my problem is now, due to the dynamic width of the parent div, the whole thing is either centered or left-aligned. This seems to be due to the new line the browser makes, when he cannot position more divs on the same row (hitting `max-width: 75%`). Each child div has a `width` of `156px` and a `margin` of `2px`.

When `#useruploads` now has a `width` of `505px`, the browser can only put three `.imagethumb` on the same line and then makes a new line - but instead of getting the `#account_thumbs` `width` of `~470px`, the browser just takes the whole space (which is why I have the issue). The fiddle below displays my dilemma.

My question is now, how can I prevent or go around this `eat the whole available space` "feature" from appearing, so that I can position `#account_thumbs` centered inside `#useruploads`, while the `.imagethumb` boxes get left aligned?

```css
#useruploads {
 display: inline-flex;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 max-width: 75%;
 min-width: 300px;
 margin-top: 0px;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 padding: 5px;
}

#account_thumbs {
 display: inline-flex;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0 auto;
 overflow: hidden;
}

#account_thumbs_clearfix {
 clear: both;
}

#user_albums {
 overflow: hidden;
}

.pageindicator {
 
}

#pageindicator_top {
 display: inline-block;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: 0px;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#pageindicator_top  a, #pageindicator_bottom  a {
 color: #2779AA !important;
}

#pageindicator_top  .ui-state-active, #pageindicator_bottom  .ui-state-active {
 color: #FFF !important;
}

#pageindicator_bottom {
 display: inline-block;
 margin-top: 10px;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: 0px;
}

.imagethumb {
 position: relative;
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 3px;
 margin: 2px;
 line-height: 0;
 width: 150px;
 height: 150px;
 background: #333 none repeat scroll 0% 0%;
 -moz-user-select: none;
 -ms-user-select: none;
 -webkit-user-select: none;
}

.imagethumb_element {
 
}

.imagethumb_element img {
 max-height: 150px;
 max-width: 150px;
}

.hover-icons {
 display: none;
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
 right: 0;
 height: 20px;
 width: 44px;
 background: rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.8) none repeat scroll 0% 0%;
}

.hover-icons-small {
 display: none;
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
 right: 0;
 height: 20px;
 width: 20px;
 background: rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.8) none repeat scroll 0% 0%;
}

.hover-icons-subelements {
 position: relative;
 margin-top: 2px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://www.anitube-nocookie.ch/res/global.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="useruploads">
 <div id="pageindicator_top" class="pageindicator">
 &nbsp;&nbsp;<a id="imagehost_pagebutton_1" class="buttons_medium ui-state-active" >1</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a id="imagehost_pagebutton_2" class="buttons_medium ui-state-active" >2</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a id="imagehost_pagebutton_3" class="buttons_medium ui-state-active" >3</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a id="imagehost_pagebutton_4" class="buttons_medium ui-state-active" >4</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a id="imagehost_pagebutton_5" class="buttons_medium ui-state-active" >5</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a id="imagehost_pagebutton_6" class="buttons_medium ui-state-active" >6</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a id="imagehost_pagebutton_7" class="buttons_medium ui-state-active" >7</a>
 </div>
 <div id="account_thumbs_clearfix">
 </div>
 <div id="account_thumbs">
 <div id="hGhh9Oi" class="imagethumb ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle"   data-pid="hGhh9Oi">
  <a class="imagethumb_element" ><img src="https://www.anitube-nocookie.ch/res/imagehost_add_album.png" /></a>
  <div id="hover-icons-hGhh9Oi" class="hover-icons ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" style="display: none;">
   <a class="cursor-pointer " ><img class="hover-icons-subelements" src="https://www.anitube-nocookie.ch/res/link_break.png"></a> <a class="cursor-pointer" ><img class="hover-icons-subelements" src="https://www.anitube-nocookie.ch/res/cross.png"></a>
  </div>
 </div><div id="3rV4fWv" class="imagethumb ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle"   data-pid="3rV4fWv">
  <a class="imagethumb_element" ><img src="https://www.anitube-nocookie.ch/res/imagehost_add_album.png" /></a>
  <div id="hover-icons-3rV4fWv" class="hover-icons ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle">
   <a class="cursor-pointer " ><img class="hover-icons-subelements" src="https://www.anitube-nocookie.ch/res/link_break.png"></a> <a class="cursor-pointer" ><img class="hover-icons-subelements" src="https://www.anitube-nocookie.ch/res/cross.png"></a>
  </div>
 </div><div id="CRoBsHA" class="imagethumb ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle"   data-pid="CRoBsHA">
  <a class="imagethumb_element" ><img src="https://www.anitube-nocookie.ch/res/imagehost_add_album.png" /></a>
  <div id="hover-icons-CRoBsHA" class="hover-icons ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" style="display: none;">
   <a class="cursor-pointer " ><img class="hover-icons-subelements" src="https://www.anitube-nocookie.ch/res/link_break.png"></a> <a class="cursor-pointer" ><img class="hover-icons-subelements" src="https://www.anitube-nocookie.ch/res/cross.png"></a>
  </div>
 </div><div id="ofU2T57" class="imagethumb ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle"   data-pid="ofU2T57">
  <a class="imagethumb_element" ><img src="https://www.anitube-nocookie.ch/res/imagehost_add_album.png" /></a>
  <div id="hover-icons-ofU2T57" class="hover-icons ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" style="display: none;">
   <a class="cursor-pointer " ><img class="hover-icons-subelements" src="https://www.anitube-nocookie.ch/res/link_break.png"></a> <a class="cursor-pointer" ><img class="hover-icons-subelements" src="https://www.anitube-nocookie.ch/res/cross.png"></a>
  </div>
 </div><div id="iLsZ3ON" class="imagethumb ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle"   data-pid="iLsZ3ON">
  <a class="imagethumb_element" ><img src="https://www.anitube-nocookie.ch/res/imagehost_add_album.png" /></a>
  <div id="hover-icons-iLsZ3ON" class="hover-icons ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" style="display: none;">
   <a class="cursor-pointer " ><img class="hover-icons-subelements" src="https://www.anitube-nocookie.ch/res/link_break.png"></a> <a class="cursor-pointer" ><img class="hover-icons-subelements" src="https://www.anitube-nocookie.ch/res/cross.png"></a>
  </div>
 </div><div id="EHM7Gw5" class="imagethumb ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle"   data-pid="EHM7Gw5">
  <a class="imagethumb_element" ><img src="https://www.anitube-nocookie.ch/res/imagehost_add_album.png" /></a>
  <div id="hover-icons-EHM7Gw5" class="hover-icons ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" style="display: none;">
   <a class="cursor-pointer " ><img class="hover-icons-subelements" src="https://www.anitube-nocookie.ch/res/link_break.png"></a> <a class="cursor-pointer" ><img class="hover-icons-subelements" src="https://www.anitube-nocookie.ch/res/cross.png"></a>
  </div>
 </div><div id="1SxMR9t" class="imagethumb ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle"   data-pid="1SxMR9t">
  <a class="imagethumb_element" ><img src="https://www.anitube-nocookie.ch/res/imagehost_add_album.png" /></a>
  <div id="hover-icons-1SxMR9t" class="hover-icons ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" style="display: none;">
   <a class="cursor-pointer " ><img class="hover-icons-subelements" src="https://www.anitube-nocookie.ch/res/link_break.png"></a> <a class="cursor-pointer" ><img class="hover-icons-subelements" src="https://www.anitube-nocookie.ch/res/cross.png"></a>
  </div>
 </div><div id="StxvBZi" class="imagethumb ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle"   data-pid="StxvBZi">
  <a class="imagethumb_element" ><img src="https://www.anitube-nocookie.ch/res/imagehost_add_album.png" /></a>
  <div id="hover-icons-StxvBZi" class="hover-icons ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" style="display: none;">
   <a class="cursor-pointer " ><img class="hover-icons-subelements" src="https://www.anitube-nocookie.ch/res/link_break.png"></a> <a class="cursor-pointer" ><img class="hover-icons-subelements" src="https://www.anitube-nocookie.ch/res/cross.png"></a>
  </div>
 </div><div id="5H2ndxU" class="imagethumb ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle"   data-pid="5H2ndxU">
  <a class="imagethumb_element" ><img src="https://www.anitube-nocookie.ch/res/imagehost_add_album.png" /></a>
  <div id="hover-icons-5H2ndxU" class="hover-icons ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" style="display: none;">
   <a class="cursor-pointer " ><img class="hover-icons-subelements" src="https://www.anitube-nocookie.ch/res/link_break.png"></a> <a class="cursor-pointer" ><img class="hover-icons-subelements" src="https://www.anitube-nocookie.ch/res/cross.png"></a>
  </div>
 </div><div id="OkHgAdu" class="imagethumb ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle"   data-pid="OkHgAdu">
  <a class="imagethumb_element" ><img src="https://www.anitube-nocookie.ch/res/imagehost_add_album.png" /></a>
  <div id="hover-icons-OkHgAdu" class="hover-icons ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" style="display: none;">
   <a class="cursor-pointer " ><img class="hover-icons-subelements" src="https://www.anitube-nocookie.ch/res/link_break.png"></a> <a class="cursor-pointer" ><img class="hover-icons-subelements" src="https://www.anitube-nocookie.ch/res/cross.png"></a>
  </div>
 </div><div id="Qbu49rU" class="imagethumb ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle"   data-pid="Qbu49rU">
  <a class="imagethumb_element" ><img src="https://www.anitube-nocookie.ch/res/imagehost_add_album.png" /></a>
  <div id="hover-icons-Qbu49rU" class="hover-icons ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" style="display: none;">
   <a class="cursor-pointer " ><img class="hover-icons-subelements" src="https://www.anitube-nocookie.ch/res/link_break.png"></a> <a class="cursor-pointer" ><img class="hover-icons-subelements" src="https://www.anitube-nocookie.ch/res/cross.png"></a>
  </div>
 </div><div id="O6HwQ5j" class="imagethumb ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle"   data-pid="O6HwQ5j">
  <a class="imagethumb_element" ><img src="https://www.anitube-nocookie.ch/res/imagehost_add_album.png" /></a>
  <div id="hover-icons-O6HwQ5j" class="hover-icons ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" style="display: none;">
   <a class="cursor-pointer " ><img class="hover-icons-subelements" src="https://www.anitube-nocookie.ch/res/link_break.png"></a> <a class="cursor-pointer" ><img class="hover-icons-subelements" src="https://www.anitube-nocookie.ch/res/cross.png"></a>
  </div>
 </div><div id="g1FmyqK" class="imagethumb ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle"   data-pid="g1FmyqK">
  <a class="imagethumb_element" ><img src="https://www.anitube-nocookie.ch/res/imagehost_add_album.png" /></a>
  <div id="hover-icons-g1FmyqK" class="hover-icons ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" style="display: none;">
   <a class="cursor-pointer " ><img class="hover-icons-subelements" src="https://www.anitube-nocookie.ch/res/link_break.png"></a> <a class="cursor-pointer" ><img class="hover-icons-subelements" src="https://www.anitube-nocookie.ch/res/cross.png"></a>
  </div>
 </div><div id="5WxObcv" class="imagethumb ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle"   data-pid="5WxObcv">
  <a class="imagethumb_element" ><img src="https://www.anitube-nocookie.ch/res/imagehost_add_album.png" /></a>
  <div id="hover-icons-5WxObcv" class="hover-icons ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" style="display: none;">
   <a class="cursor-pointer " ><img class="hover-icons-subelements" src="https://www.anitube-nocookie.ch/res/link_break.png"></a> <a class="cursor-pointer" ><img class="hover-icons-subelements" src="https://www.anitube-nocookie.ch/res/cross.png"></a>
  </div>
 </div>
  <div id="account_thumbs_clearfix"></div>
 </div>
 <div id="account_thumbs_clearfix">
 </div>
 <div id="pageindicator_bottom" class="pageindicator">
 &nbsp;&nbsp;<a id="imagehost_pagebutton_1" class="buttons_medium ui-state-active" >1</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a id="imagehost_pagebutton_2" class="buttons_medium ui-state-active" >2</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a id="imagehost_pagebutton_3" class="buttons_medium ui-state-active" >3</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a id="imagehost_pagebutton_4" class="buttons_medium ui-state-active" >4</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a id="imagehost_pagebutton_5" class="buttons_medium ui-state-active" >5</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a id="imagehost_pagebutton_6" class="buttons_medium ui-state-active" >6</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a id="imagehost_pagebutton_7" class="buttons_medium ui-state-active" >7</a>
 </div>
 <div id="account_thumbs_clearfix">
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I will strongly recommend using flex-box for this. The positioning can all be done in 2-3 lines of CSS. Great guide to getting started using flex-box CSS here: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: I've tried `inline-flex` before, but haven't had any luck (using the same guide). Do you think `flex-box` will work better? @Korgrue

Comment: inline-flex is part of flex-box. 
put: justify-content: flex-start; and align-items:center on the container div. Remove all other positioning on the children.

Comment: @Korgrue I've done that, but the browser still decides to take up all the available horizontal space, instead of only the width of all child divs lined up. Thus ending up with the whole block left-aligned. https://i.stack.imgur.com/xr2sT.png

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly, the result you're looking for is for the last row to appear centered within the layout. What is happening is your containing div for the thumbnails is already occupying the entire space provided by its parent. It's centered, but the left margin is now along the left margin of its container. This margin is a straight line that runs the full height of the container.

As a result, your individual thumbs, which are left aligned, are obediently lining up with the left edge of their container for its full height. You might try adding a new containing div for each line, or adjusting the alignment on the thumbs themselves, rather than the parent.

Comment: Actually I want the individual thumbs to be left aligned. The parent div of these thumbs should be centered inside the page (or his parent div to be accurate).